# Get the size of a displayed image inside a WPF ImageControl

Tags: c#, wpf, image, display

I have an image inside an image control of WPF.

How can I get the displayed size of the image inside the imageControl with the height and width converted to IN?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly "*the displayed size*" means. Besides that, WPF display units are 96 DPI, which means *dots per inch*, so if something is for example 96 units wide, thats one inch. Assuming you display settings are sufficiently precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested [Tam Bui's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71575162), it does not work properly when the image size is smaller than the image control size.

My solution:

First convert the `Image.Source` to `MemoryStream` with `ImageSourceToMemoryStream` (my method), then convert it to `BitmapImage` and finally get the height and width of `BitmapImage`.

Output (tested in Visual Studio 2017, .Net Framework 4.5.2):

I tested it on png and HD jpg images.

PNG:

[image: PNG]

HD JPG:

[image: HD JPG]

XAML:

```
    <Image x:Name="ImageControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="113" Margin="56,42,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="159"/>
    <Button x:Name="ChooseImage" Content="Choose image" Click="ChooseImage_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="392,276,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90"/>
    <Button x:Name="CalculateImageSize" Content="Calculate image size" Click="CalculateImageSize_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="257,276,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

C#:

Note: `BitmapEncoder` must be set to `GifBitmapEncoder` to calculate the size of HD images (or higher), otherwise it will not return the correct result.

```
    int Height = 0;
    int Width = 0;
    public System.IO.MemoryStream ImageSourceToMemoryStream(BitmapEncoder BitEncoder, ImageSource ImgSource)
    {
        System.IO.MemoryStream Stream = null;
        switch ((ImgSource as BitmapSource) != null)
        {
            case true:
                BitEncoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create((ImgSource as BitmapSource)));
                Stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
                BitEncoder.Save(Stream);
                break;
        }
        return Stream;
    }
    private void ChooseImage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog OP = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
        OP.Filter= "All files (*.*)|*.*|JPG (*.jpg)|*.jpg|BMP (*.bmp)|*.bmp|GIF (*.gif)|*.gif|PNG (*.png)|*.png";
        OP.AutoUpgradeEnabled = false;
        if (OP.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            var IMG = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(OP.FileName);
            BitmapImage BitMapImage = new BitmapImage();
            BitMapImage.BeginInit();
            System.IO.MemoryStream MemoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            IMG.Save(MemoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            MemoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
            BitMapImage.StreamSource = MemoryStream;
            BitMapImage.EndInit();
            ImageControl.Source = BitMapImage;
        }
    }
    private void CalculateImageSize_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BitmapImage BitMapImage = new BitmapImage();
        BitMapImage.BeginInit();
        //BitmapEncoder must be set to GifBitmapEncoder to calculate the size of HD images (or higher), otherwise it will not return the correct result
        var MemoryStream = ImageSourceToMemoryStream(new GifBitmapEncoder(), ImageControl.Source);
        MemoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
        BitMapImage.StreamSource = MemoryStream;
        BitMapImage.EndInit();
        Height = (int)BitMapImage.Height;
        Width = (int)BitMapImage.Width;
        ImageControl.Source = BitMapImage;
        Size DisplayedImageSize = new Size(Width, Height);
        MessageBox.Show("Image control width = " + ImageControl.Width.ToString() + ", Image width = " + Width.ToString() + ", Image control height = " + ImageControl.Height.ToString() + ", Image height = " + Height.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Size displayedImageSize = new Size((int)imageControl.ActualWidth, (int)imageControl.ActualHeight);
```